# Why is Typescript telling me type X is a different subtype from ITSELF?

Tags: typescript

The real-world code where I'm having this problem involves passing around redux `Reducer`s with specific `Action` subtypes, but for simplicity's sake I wrote the following example that also demonstrates the problem:

```js
interface FooBox<T = any> {
    foo: T
}

type FooAction<ReturnType = any, F extends FooBox = FooBox> = (fooBox: F) => ReturnType;

function acceptFooBoxAction(fooAction: FooAction<any, FooBox>) {
    // do stuff
}

function acceptFooBoxOrSubtypeAction<F extends FooBox = FooBox>(fooAction: FooAction<any, F>) {
    acceptFooBoxAction(fooAction); // <------ ERROR ON THIS LINE
}
```

The full error that I get is

```
Argument of type 'FooAction<any, F>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FooAction<any, FooBox<any>>'.
  Type 'FooBox<any>' is not assignable to type 'F'.
    'FooBox<any>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'F', but 'F' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'FooBox<any>'.
```

Please note that the types named at the beginning and end of the last line are *the same*: `FooBox<any>`.  So, if I am reading this correctly, it is telling me that `FooBox<any>` is a different subtype from *itself*.

## Wut.

And if I am *not* reading this correctly... *how do I read this correctly*? `щ(ಥДಥщ)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of the error is apparently the intended behavior of [`--strictFunctionTypes` mode](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) (though the error's text being nonsensical is probably less intended).  The error goes away if I put `"strictFunctionTypes": false` in my tsconfig.json.  Unfortunately, this also causes brand new errors to appear that are much less easily solved, so I'll just have to live with writing repetitively verbose function types as [uamanager suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458391/why-is-typescript-telling-me-type-x-is-a-different-subtype-from-itself#answer-62458539).

Answer (score 0):

Adding type to `acceptFooBoxAction` solves your problem.

```js
interface FooBox<T = any> {
    foo: T
}

type FooAction<ReturnType = any, F extends FooBox = FooBox> = (fooBox: F) => ReturnType;

function acceptFooBoxAction<F extends FooBox = FooBox>(fooAction: FooAction<any, F>) {
    // do stuff
}

function acceptFooBoxOrSubtypeAction<F extends FooBox = FooBox>(fooAction: FooAction<any, F>) {
    acceptFooBoxAction(fooAction);
}
```

Problem is that `acceptFooBoxAction` function accepts action with type `FooAction<any, FooBox>`, but `FooAction` in this case is not the same as `F` type passed from `acceptFooBoxOrSubtypeAction` function.